# Añadir una columna ficticia al hacer select en Redshift

Tags: sql

¿Es posible añadir una columna ficticia a la hora de realizar un `select`en SQL Redshift?

Yo estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla del sistema (concretamente, a `stv_wlm_query_state`) y en función de si el campo `exec_time`es mayor de 4 horas, debe aparecer en dicha columna el valor WARNING y si es mayor de 8 horas, el valor debe ser CRITICAL.

¿Es posible?

La tabla antes mencionada, contiene los siguientes campos:

`xid    task    query   service_class   slot_count  wlm_start_time  state   queue_time  exec_time`.

Una fila cualquiera de resultado sería:

`58992537   1262584 1269123 8   1   2019-03-20 06:53:18 Returning 0 2129442104`.

Yo necesito añadir esa columna "virtual", llamada por ejemplo "Evaluacion", cuyo contenido dependerá del valor de exec_time. Si este es mayor de cuatro horas, debe salir en esa columna virtual el valor WARNING; en caso de ser mayor de ocho, el valor debe ser CRITICAL.

El select que utilizo es el siguiente:

`select query as idquery,queue_time as tiempo_en_cola_microseg,exec_time as tiempo_ejecucion_microseg,(tiempo_en_cola_microseg+tiempo_ejecucion_microseg) as tiempo_total_microseg ,state as estado,
mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/3600000000) as integer),24) || ':' || mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/60000000) as integer),60) || ':' || mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/1000000) as integer),60) as duracion_hhmmss
from stv_wlm_query_state
where tiempo_total_microseg >= 14400000000;`

He añadido la recomendación de @PatricioMoracho de utilizar `CASE` en mi `select` y me ha funcionado perfectamente:

```
`case tiempo_total_microseg
when tiempo_total_microseg>28800000000
then 'CRITICAL' else 'WARNING'
end as situacion`
```

Comment: Bueno, tampoco la llames ficticia, sería una columna de la consulta con todos sus derechos, bien un campo calculado o una proyección extendida :) Pásanos el SQL de la tabla, algún dato para ver el resultado y te lo hacemos rápidamente.

Comment: Algo así `CASE WHEN exec_time > 4 THEN 'WARNING' ELSE '' END` te funciona?

Comment: @David, he editado la pregunta para que sea más completa.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho he probado con `CASE WHEN` y funciona perfectamente. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¡Genial! Me alegra que te haya servido la recomendación... anota la solución como respuesta y márcala como respondida. Puedes dejar la respuesta en la pregunta, pero mejor que se vea que ya está resuelta :) Además, veo que ya has votado a Patricio, ¡bien! Aquí te dejo las recomendaciones del sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Nos vemos por aquí, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo las indicaciones de @PatricioMoracho en los comentarios de mi pregunta, adjunté un `CASE WHEN, solucionando así mi problema.

Dejo a continuación la solución:

```
select query as idquery,wlm_start_time as inicio,queue_time as 
tiempo_en_cola_microseg,exec_time as tiempo_ejecucion_microseg, 
(tiempo_en_cola_microseg+tiempo_ejecucion_microseg) as tiempo_total_microseg ,state as estado,
mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/3600000000) as integer),24) || ':' || 
mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/60000000) as integer),60) || ':' || 
mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/1000000) as integer),60)  as duracion_hhmmss,
case tiempo_total_microseg
when tiempo_total_microseg>28800000000
then 'CRITICAL' else 'WARNING'
end as situacion
from stv_wlm_query_state
where tiempo_total_microseg >= 14400000000
order by duracion_hhmmss;
```